# Change R code into Python code , maximum likelihood of logistic regression

Tags: python, r

I want to apply maximum likelihood into logistic regression in my project.I found the R code and want to transfer into Python code. However, my python code has no output and I am not sure it is correct. Can someone evaluate my code?
Here is the R code:

```
# Define the log-likelihood function 
# ln L = sum_i [y_i log(p(x_i,beta0,beta1)) + (1-y_i) log(1-p(x_i,beta0,beta1)) ]
loglike <- function(beta0,beta1,x,y) {
  # Define the logistic function 
  logit <- function(x,beta0,beta1) {
    1/(1 + exp(-beta0-beta1*x))
  }

  p <- logit(x,beta0,beta1)
  sum( y*log(p) + (1-y)*log(1-p) )
}

find_betaMC <- function(N, beta0_range, beta1_range, x, y) {
  # Generate N random values of beta0 and beta1 in the specified ranges.
  many_beta0 <- runif(N, beta0_range[1], beta0_range[2])
  many_beta1 <- runif(N, beta1_range[1], beta1_range[2])
  # Calculate the ln(likelihood) for these beta0 and beta1
  loglikelihood <- mapply(loglike, many_beta0,many_beta1, MoreArgs=list(x=x,y=y))
  # Search for maximum
  ind_max <- which.max(loglikelihood)
  output <- c(many_beta0[ind_max],many_beta1[ind_max],loglikelihood[ind_max])
  names(output) <- c("beta0", "beta1", "ln(likelihood)")
  output
}
```

And here is my Python code:

```
def loglike(beta0, beta1, X_test, y_test):
    def logit(x, beta0, beta1):
        result=1/(1 + exp(-beta0-beta1*x))
        return result
    p=logit(X_test, beta0, beta1)
    res=sum(y_test*log(p) + (1-y_test)*log(1-p))
    return res
def betaMC(X_test, y_test):
    many_beta0=random.uniform(1, 50)
    many_beta1=random.uniform(1, 50)
    loglikelihood=[many_beta0, many_beta1, X_test, y_test].lapply(loglike)
    ind_max=max(loglikelihood)
    output=[mant_beta0[ind_max], many_beta1[in_max], loglikelihood[ind_max]]
    print(output)
```

here is my data url:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6PZi1oMqIQJP5f9MVtYRpdPG8dbWP9cD0mCRNsTEYw/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv

Also, here is my code of performing logistic regression:

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6PZi1oMqIQJP5f9MVtYRpdPG8dbWP9cD0mCRNsTEYw/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.drop(['ssc_b','hsc_b'], axis=1, inplace=True)
X = df[['gender', 'ssc_p', 'hsc_p', 'hsc_s', 'degree_p', 'degree_t', 'workex','etest_p', 'specialisation', 'mba_p',]]
y = df['status']
#Reverse Mapping and making Categorical
X["gender"] = pd.Categorical(X.gender.map({0:"M",1:"F"}))
X["hsc_s"] = pd.Categorical(X.hsc_s.map({0:"Commerce",1:"Science",2:"Arts"}))
X["degree_t"] = pd.Categorical(X.degree_t.map({0:"Comm&Mgmt",1:"Sci&Tech",2:"Others"}))
X["workex"] = pd.Categorical(X.workex.map({0:"No",1:"Yes"}))
X["specialisation"] = pd.Categorical(X.specialisation.map({0:"Mkt&HR",1:"Mkt&Fin"}))
X = pd.get_dummies(X)
colmunn_names = X.columns.to_list()
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y, test_size=0.3)
logistic_reg = LogisticRegression()
logistic_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = logistic_reg.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: you haven't quite got a [mcve] here: can you provide us a data set etc. that we would need to actually run your code (rather than staring at it hoping an error will be obvious)?  Debugging tip: try running your log-likelihood function on a few sets of parameters by hand to see if it gives sensible answers.

Comment: your second function doesn't have a return statement.

Comment: providing the data is nice.  Can you provide code that reads it in and applies your functions?  (We can write that for ourselves, but we shouldn't have to ...)

Comment: what single X variable are you using in your MLE?

Comment: test data, X_test, but I am not sure if using all the independent variable or just test data.

Comment: but I think `X_test` is a matrix and your Python code looks like it assumes a scalar ...